# solve symbolic system of equations inside an array

Tags: matlab, system, equation

I have two `1x63` arrays, `landa` and `v`. Each of their members are `syms`, and each `v` member is a function of all `landa` members.
I have already calculated the `v` members and they are all symbolic equations function of `landa1 ... landa63`.
For example `v(2)` is:

```
- (26032168169837596*landa_1_1)/1818071823710369  ...
- (1248281001603436*landa_1_3)/86484908042379 ...
- (52625347239733568*landa_1_4)/7261479255655197 ...
- (6604602588458826*landa_1_5)/1360945351882651 ...
- (13266428887920030*landa_1_6)/3627728680706743 ...
- (13328946369600138*landa_1_7)/4532912553538921 ...
- (13397783439780820*landa_1_8)/5437431490145639 ...
- (4491362061290848*landa_1_9)/2113747029461023 ...
- (13559659774820030*landa_1_10)/7244344326692733 ...
- (6828247388123141*landa_1_11)/4073339103373161 ...
- (3442454859315376*landa_1_12)/2266553892078633 ...
- (6949066850632307*landa_1_13)/4983366792250084 ...
- (7024497445184291*landa_1_14)/5433118949496761 ...
- (889387874167034*landa_1_15)/735290915649273 ...
- (3586600796756319*landa_1_16)/3049079330330816 ...
- (7244103336161213*landa_1_17)/6322929884842724 ...
- (3663915377012426*landa_1_18)/3273799694605737 ...
- (7427507175063298*landa_1_19)/6772119170494125 ...
- (7547295597229107*landa_1_20)/6996432151091905 ...
- (1923338048147995*landa_1_21)/1805121116217713 ...
- (7874362398733741*landa_1_22)/7444211507963693 ...
- (4051684049941553*landa_1_23)/3833776207492451 ...
- (8331733241914890*landa_1_24)/7845891307457161 ...
- (8606531462572406*landa_1_25)/8023896565108419 ...
- (8756096133405978*landa_1_26)/8112761886216707 ...
- (4477082052693931*landa_1_29)/4189433684998512 ...
- (4293059637590261*landa_1_30)/4233768184335278 ...
- (4967757600021511*landa_1_32)/77075937264547968615886243233792 ...
- (2274910796541161*landa_1_34)/8470743025804629 ...
- (6028337215106101*landa_1_35)/16766874508660884 ...
- (434117063192273*landa_1_36)/1036973999581658 ...
- (3802611183306680*landa_1_37)/8207893792607821 ...
- (8115962046780543*landa_1_38)/16239563076236596 ...
- (4264630823999399*landa_1_39)/8031489540592591 ...
- (382070995992493*landa_1_40)/654536108370494 ...
- (1206382478629297*landa_1_41)/1919215219152206 ...
- (5057377064996180*landa_1_42)/7454301295942339 ...
- (5238466105690712*landa_1_43)/7231219638064483 ...
- (5384852859880393*landa_1_44)/7007714246020179 ...
- (56761628997640*landa_1_45)/69936892400419 ...
- (5607644779348011*landa_1_46)/6559787230544288 ...
- (5694155621326436*landa_1_47)/6335516873838327 ...
- (5768331379800997*landa_1_48)/6111131481923240 ...
- (5829886618525661*landa_1_49)/5895672906607196 ...
- (5928984667335071*landa_1_50)/5447442533826811 ...
- (1520446165159822*landa_1_52)/1137305157592641 ...
- (409597577403863*landa_1_53)/272688134034879 ...
- (12394543279688924*landa_1_54)/7280059714659769 ...
- (832603741914514*landa_1_55)/425254609909857 ...
- (12573597782885200*landa_1_56)/5477098860424583 ...
- (6325031977448627*landa_1_57)/2287526886867664 ...
- (6359844452086436*landa_1_58)/1836534772502583 ...
- (25567126758252096*landa_1_59)/5543811068392643 ...
- (51370713192797208*landa_1_60)/7494668753437699 ...
- (25795907362066832*landa_1_61)/1976172947874511 ...
- (20234459321830409375*landa_1_62)/454300612410998784 ...
- (1299970916679950*landa_1_63)/91626708293577 ...
- (288230376151711744*1049^(1/2)*landa_1_27)/8603414113545292505 ...
- (5629499534213120*17146^(1/2)*landa_1_31)/729733163812670453 ...
- (112589990684262400*19121^(1/2)*landa_1_33)/81400055837869623247 ...
- (171136785840078848*20261^(1/2)*landa_1_51)/20255345682677877255 ...
- (225179981368524800*40081^(1/2)*landa_1_28)/41535093106204407301
```

Now, I want to solve each `v(i) = 0`; I have 63 equations and 63 unknowns, `landa(i)`.
How should I solve this system?

Comment: Why symbolically? Your equation seems to be in `Ax=b` format. It feels like your should create an A matrix, a b matrix (zeros) and do `lambdas=A\b`.

Comment: how should i do that? i have no idea to create A here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is done (if the eq is in the format you have) with an `Ax=b` system.

Let me show you how to do it with a simple example of 2 eq with 2 unknowns.

```
3*l1-4*l2=3
5*l1 -3*l2=-4
```

You can build the system as:

`x` (unknowns) will be a `unknowns x 1` size matrix. 
`A` is a `equations x unknonws` matrix
`b` is a `equations x 1` matrix.

for the example:

```
A=[3 -4 
   5 -3];
b=[3
   -4]
x=A\b;
```

Comment: but one more problem...how can i find A width landa s i have now??? i must find a way to get factors of each landa and put it in A . how should i find that?

Comment: @user2635676 I canot find how to do it, but certainly you have built that symbolic matrix somehow. Cant you just not build it symbolically and just plug the numbers?